# How to use OS specific library path in cgo?

Tags: c, go, cgo

I wrote a golang code which calls a C library function. But in case I want to cross-compile it for other operating systems such as Linux/MacOS/Windows, how do I setup custom path to a library in `#cgo CFLAGS` and `#cgo LDFLAGS`?

I tried this example:

```golang
// platform.go
package main

/*

#if defined(_WIN64)
    #define LIB_PATH "lib/win64"
#elif defined(__linux__)
    #define LIB_PATH "lib/linux"
#elif defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__) // Apple OSX and iOS (Darwin)
    #define LIB_PATH "lib/darwin"
#endif

#cgo CFLAGS: -I./include
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L./${LIB_PATH} -lsaplinglib -lpthread -ldl

#include "saplinglib.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Return a name of platform, if determined, otherwise - an empty string
const char *get_platform_name() {
    return (LIB_PATH == NULL) ? "" : LIB_PATH;
}

int test() {
    puts(get_platform_name());
    return 0;
}

*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fromC := C.int(0)
    fromC = C.test()
    fmt.Println(C.int(fromC))
}
```

But it errors out in output:

```sh
go run platform.go
/Users/satinder/example/platform.go: malformed #cgo argument: -L./${LIB_PATH}
```

As example my library's tree looks something like this:

```sh
➜  example tree
.
├── include
│   └── saplinglib.h
├── lib
│   ├── darwin
│   │   └── libsaplinglib.a
│   ├── linux
│   │   └── libsaplinglib.a
│   └── win64
│       └── saplinglib.lib
└── platform.go

5 directories, 5 files
```

My coding environment is MacOS, so I do my coding and testing on MacOS/Darwin compiled library.

But I need to automate this all to cross-compile on a Linux machine, to make binaries for Linux/MacOS/Windows.

I tried looking for cgo related questions, which suggested to try `pkg-config`, but the answers didn't clear much on how. In case I could use `pkg-config`, can someone please give some example pkg-config contents etc for my use case? Would really appreciate for your help.

Thanks,
Satinder

Comment: I don't think cgo supports cross-compile yet.